# Javascript code not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

Below is my java script code which does not seem to work in Internet Explorer -

```
window.onload = function() {
    function openWindow(modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => { document.addEventListener('click', closeModal); });
}

function closeWindow(modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(() => { document.removeEventListener('click', closeModal); });
}

function closeModal(e) {
    const modal = getModalRoot(e.target);
    if (modal) return;

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip_modal'), closeWindow);
}

function getModalRoot(element) {
    if (!element || !element.classList) return null;
    if (element.classList.contains('modal-content')) return element;
    return getModalRoot(element.parentNode);
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip_icon'), (x, i) => {
    x.id = `opener${i}`;    
    const modal = x.querySelector(`#${x.id} ~ .tooltip_modal`);

    x.addEventListener('click', () => { openWindow(modal); });  
    modal.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', () => { closeWindow(modal); });
});
};
```

And I am unable to figure out whats wrong. What needs to be done to make it work in Internet Explorer.

JS fiddle code - https://jsfiddle.net/2orwct27/9/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `() =>` - Ineternet Exploder does NOT understand ES2015+ arrow function syntax ... use a transpiler if you must support ancient browsers :p

Comment: The first thing to do is to open the developer tools (F12) and check what the console is reporting (any errors).

Comment: Debugging 101 hint: Browser Developer Tools Console - shows errors!

Comment: Everything from above, as well as specifically what version of Internet Explorer is manifesting the problem.

Comment: secondly, IE does not understand ```` template literals - again, a transpiler will produce IE runnable code for you

Comment: Also string interpolation (`opener${i}`) is only supported by modern browsers.

Comment: @flyer - aren't they called template literals? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals :p

Comment: Can this code be modified so that it is supported by IE as well?

Comment: @JaromandaX whoops yeah, my bad.

Comment: yes, as I've mentioned twice, use a transpiler - babel is one such transpiler - paste your code here http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&code_lz=Q and see - though, you don't want to be using the babel online REPL like that for all your coding - read the docs at babel